# Multiple Label Frame, tkinter GUI did not match the specific row and column

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I create 2 frame in column 1 in my program, the first one is ok, i use sticky = N,it position properly at the top, but for the next frame, it does not appear at the bottom of my program, here is the

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/01sSf.jpg]

here is how i define the first frame:

```
def DateSelection(self):
    self.SelectDateFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="Period Selection",height= 215,width =260)
    self.SelectDateFrame.grid(row= 0, column=1,padx=2,sticky=N)
    self.SelectDateFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    instructionLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="Enter a date or use the select date button.")
    instructionLabel.grid(row =1,column=1)

    startDateLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="Start Date:")
    startDateLabel.grid(row =2,column=1,sticky=W)

    startDate_ent =Entry(self.SelectDateFrame,width=40)
    startDate_ent.grid(row =3, column =1,padx=6,pady=6)

    endDateLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="End Date:")
    endDateLabel.grid(row =5,column=1,sticky=W)

    endDate_ent =Entry(self.SelectDateFrame,width=40)
    endDate_ent.grid(row =6, column =1,padx=6,pady=6)

    # Create the Select start date and Select end date button for UAH
    StartDatebtn = Button(self.SelectDateFrame, text="Select Start Date", command=printMessage,height =1, width =12)
    StartDatebtn.grid(row=4,column=1)

    EndDatebtn = Button(self.SelectDateFrame, text="Select End Date", command=printMessage,height =1, width =12)
    EndDatebtn.grid(row=7,column= 1)
```

This is the second frame code which did not appear below the first frame in my program:

```
def UASuggestion(self):
    self.SuggestUAFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="Case Suggestion for UA",height= 220,width =220)
    self.SuggestUAFrame.grid(row=8, column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky=N,)
    self.SuggestUAFrame.grid_propagate(0)
```

I think can set the grid_rowconfigure and grid_columnconfigure but not sure how this can fix in my code,Regards.

Complete coding:

```
from tkinter import *

class ConfigureUAinterface(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.minsize(width=700, height=500)
        root.maxsize(width=700, height=500)
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        Grid.config(self)
        self.ConfigurationUA()
        self.DateSelection()
        self.UASuggestion()

    def ConfigurationUA(self):
        self.UAHFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="User Activity History",height= 495,width =200)
        self.UAHFrame.grid(row= 0, column=0,padx=2)
        self.UAHFrame.grid_propagate(0)

    def setUACheck():
        Jumplistvar.set(True)
        USBDevicevar.set(True)
        Prefetchvar.set(True)
        UserAssistvar.set(True)
        WindowsSearchvar.set(True)
        GoogleSearchHistoryvar.set(True)
        NetworkProfilevar.set(True)
        DownloadHistoryvar.set(True)
        InstallProgramCheckvar.set(True)
        MRUvar.set(True)
        ShellBagvar.set(True)
        BrowserHistoryvar.set(True)
        BrowserFormHistoryvar.set(True)

    def setUAUNCheck():
        Jumplistvar.set(False)
        USBDevicevar.set(False)
        Prefetchvar.set(False)
        UserAssistvar.set(False)
        WindowsSearchvar.set(False)
        GoogleSearchHistoryvar.set(False)
        NetworkProfilevar.set(False)
        DownloadHistoryvar.set(False)
        InstallProgramCheckvar.set(False)
        MRUvar.set(False)
        ShellBagvar.set(False)
        BrowserHistoryvar.set(False)
        BrowserFormHistoryvar.set(False)

    #Set the UAH variable as a booloean
    Jumplistvar = BooleanVar()
    Jumplistvar.set(False)
    JumplistCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Jumplist", variable=Jumplistvar)
    JumplistCheck.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)

    USBDevicevar = BooleanVar()
    USBDevicevar.set(False)
    USBDeviceCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="USB Device", variable=USBDevicevar)
    USBDeviceCheck.grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)

    Prefetchvar = BooleanVar()
    Prefetchvar.set(False)
    PrefetchCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Prefetch", variable=Prefetchvar)
    PrefetchCheck.grid(row=3,column=0,sticky=W)

    UserAssistvar = BooleanVar()
    UserAssistvar.set(False)
    UserAssistCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="User Assist", variable=UserAssistvar)
    UserAssistCheck.grid(row=4,column=0,sticky=W)

    WindowsSearchvar = BooleanVar()
    WindowsSearchvar.set(False)
    WindowsSearchCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Windows Search", variable=WindowsSearchvar)
    WindowsSearchCheck.grid(row=5,column=0,sticky=W)

    GoogleSearchHistoryvar = BooleanVar()
    GoogleSearchHistoryvar.set(False)
    GoogleSearchHistoryCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Google Search History",
                                           variable=GoogleSearchHistoryvar)
    GoogleSearchHistoryCheck.grid(row=6,column=0,sticky=W)

    NetworkProfilevar = BooleanVar()
    NetworkProfilevar.set(False)
    NetworkProfileCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Network Profile", variable=NetworkProfilevar)
    NetworkProfileCheck.grid(row=7,column=0,sticky=W)

    DownloadHistoryvar = BooleanVar()
    DownloadHistoryvar.set(False)
    DownloadHistoryCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Download History", variable=DownloadHistoryvar)
    DownloadHistoryCheck.grid(row=8,column=0,sticky=W)

    InstallProgramCheckvar = BooleanVar()
    InstallProgramCheckvar.set(False)
    InstallProgramCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Install Programs", variable=InstallProgramCheckvar)
    InstallProgramCheck.grid(row=9,column=0,sticky=W)

    MRUvar = BooleanVar()
    MRUvar.set(False)
    MRUCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Most Recently Used(MRU) List", variable=MRUvar)
    MRUCheck.grid(row=10,column=0,sticky=W)

    ShellBagvar = BooleanVar()
    ShellBagvar.set(False)
    ShellBagCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="ShellBag", variable=ShellBagvar)
    ShellBagCheck.grid(row=11,column=0,sticky=W)

    BrowserHistoryvar = BooleanVar()
    BrowserHistoryvar.set(False)
    BrowserHistoryCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Browser History", variable=BrowserHistoryvar)
    BrowserHistoryCheck.grid(row=12,column=0,sticky=W)

    BrowserFormHistoryvar = BooleanVar()
    BrowserFormHistoryvar.set(False)
    BrowserFormHistoryCheck = Checkbutton(self.UAHFrame,text="Browser Form History", variable=BrowserFormHistoryvar)
    BrowserFormHistoryCheck.grid(row=13,column=0,sticky=W)

    # Create the check and uncheck button for UAH
    UACheckbtn = Button(self.UAHFrame, text="Check all UA", command=setUACheck,height =2, width =21)
    UACheckbtn.grid(row=14,column= 0,pady=6,padx=18)

    UAunCheckbtn = Button(self.UAHFrame, text="Uncheck all UA", command=setUAUNCheck,height =2, width =21)
    UAunCheckbtn.grid(row=15,column= 0,pady=6,padx=18)

    def DateSelection(self):
        self.SelectDateFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="Period Selection",height= 215,width =260)
        self.SelectDateFrame.grid(row= 0, column=1,padx=2,sticky=N)
        self.SelectDateFrame.grid_propagate(0)

        instructionLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="Enter a date or use the select date button.")
        instructionLabel.grid(row =1,column=1)

        startDateLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="Start Date:")
        startDateLabel.grid(row =2,column=1,sticky=W)

        startDate_ent =Entry(self.SelectDateFrame,width=40)
        startDate_ent.grid(row =3, column =1,padx=6,pady=6)

        endDateLabel=Label(self.SelectDateFrame,text="End Date:")
        endDateLabel.grid(row =5,column=1,sticky=W)

        endDate_ent =Entry(self.SelectDateFrame,width=40)
        endDate_ent.grid(row =6, column =1,padx=6,pady=6)

        # Create the Select start date and Select end date button for UAH
        StartDatebtn = Button(self.SelectDateFrame, text="Select Start Date", command=printMessage,height =1, width =12)
        StartDatebtn.grid(row=4,column=1)

        EndDatebtn = Button(self.SelectDateFrame, text="Select End Date", command=printMessage,height =1, width =12)
        EndDatebtn.grid(row=7,column= 1)

    def UASuggestion(self):
        self.SuggestUAFrame = LabelFrame(self,text="Case Suggestion for UA",height= 220,width =220)
        self.SuggestUAFrame.grid(row=8, column=1,padx=2,pady=2,sticky=N,)
        self.SuggestUAFrame.grid_propagate(0)

def printMessage():
    print("Wow this actually worked!")

root = Tk()
root.title("UA Configuration")
cuai= ConfigureUAinterface(root)
root.mainloop()
```

: This is a screenshot showing how "Case Suggestion" fails to appear right below "Period Selection" 
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AewDk.jpg)

Comment: `class ConfigureUAinterface(Frame):` leave old style gui building style !

Comment: Your code got more copy paste, why waste your time ?

Comment: than what should i do? Regards?

Comment: or you mean using for loop?

Comment: @dsgdfg: what does "leave old style gui building style" mean?" Inheriting from `Frame` is a perfectly normal thing to do. It's not 'old style'.

Comment: Your picture has a "User Activity History" frame and a "Period Selection" frame, but not a "Case Suggestion for UI frame" which is your second block of code. It's not clear which frame "the second frame" refers to in your question. Is "Case Suggestion..." supposed to be below "Period Selection" or below "User Activity History"? Can you please provide a complete, minimal example? For example, you don't need all those radiobuttons to illustrate relative placement of the frames.

Comment: "Case Suggestion" should be right below "Period Selection". If I remove the coding of the checkbutton/checkbox widget, "Case Suggestion" will move up to just below "Period Selection". That's why I showed the relevant coding in my question.

Comment: I attached a screenshot you can check it at the end of the question

Comment: Your indentation seems broken in your "complete coding".

Comment: Bryan Oakley, i already edit it, thanks for your remind

Comment: For your information the complete code will not show the case suggestion, it will appear only resize the User Activity History labelframe smaller, it will look like what i post in edited screenshot

Answer (score 0):

The frame is appearing exactly where you tell it to appear. You placed "Case suggestion ..." in row 8, which means it must appear below row 0. However, row 0 is very tall, which means anything below it will be off the visible part of the screen since you forced the screen to be a specific size and don't allow it to be re-sized.

If I understand what you want ("Case suggestion..." immediately below "Period Selection"), you need to do two things for a quick and dirty fix:

1. move "Case suggestion..." to row 1, and
2. make "User Activity History" span two rows

For example:

```
self.UAHFrame.grid(row= 0, column=0, rowspan=2, ...)
...
self.SuggestUAFrame.grid(row=1, column=1,...)
```